# Error en Trigger "AFTER INSERT ON..." de MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger, mariadb

estoy teniendo problemas con la creación de un trigger en mysql, pero no se porque me está causando error. La tabla en la que quiero insertar una vez se active el trigger es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `reportes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipoCambio` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fechaCambio` date NOT NULL,
  `rut` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `idCredencial` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reserva` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `horario` varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Y el trigger es este:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER agregaReserva AFTER INSERT ON reserva
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE tRut VARCHAR(10);
SELECT u.rut INTO @tRut FROM reserva r 
INNER JOIN credencial c ON r.idCredencial = c.id
INNER JOIN usuario u ON c.id = u.idCredencial 
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

DECLARE tFechaAct DATE;
SELECT CURDATE() INTO @tFechaAct;

DECLARE tNombre VARCHAR(20);
SELECT u.nombre INTO @tNombre FROM reserva r 
INNER JOIN credencial c ON r.idCredencial = c.id
INNER JOIN usuario u ON c.id = u.idCredencial 
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

DECLARE tReserva VARCHAR(80);
SELECT CONCAT(tr.tipo, ' Nº ', tr.numeroDispositivo) AS reserva 
INTO @tReserva FROM tiporeserva tr 
INNER JOIN reserva r ON tr.id = r.idTipoReserva
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

DECLARE tHorario VARCHAR(20);
SELECT CONCAT(h.horaComienzo, ' - ', h.horaFin) 
INTO @tHorario FROM horario h
INNER JOIN reserva r ON h.bloque = r.bloqueHorario
WHERE r.id = NEW.id

INSERT INTO `reportes`(`tipoCambio`, `fechaCambio`, `rut`, `nombre`, `idCredencial`, `reserva`, `horario`) VALUES ('Reserva', @tFechaAct, @tRut, @tNombre, NEW.idCredencial, @tReserva, @tHorario);
END //
```

Finalmente, el error que menciona es:

> Error MySQL ha dicho:
>
> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'DECLARE tFechaAct DATE; SELECT CURDATE() INTO @tFechaAct;
>
> DECLARE tNombre VA' en la linea 11 Abrir nueva ventana de phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que tienes es que no declaras las variables locales en el principio del bloque, MySQL exige colocar al inicio del bloque todos los DECLARE. Para solucionar este error debes colocar tu código de la siguiente forma:

**Tu disparador:**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER agregaReserva AFTER INSERT ON reserva
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE tRut VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE tFechaAct DATE;
DECLARE tNombre VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE tReserva VARCHAR(80);
DECLARE tHorario VARCHAR(20);

SELECT u.rut INTO @tRut FROM reserva r 
INNER JOIN credencial c ON r.idCredencial = c.id
INNER JOIN usuario u ON c.id = u.idCredencial 
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

SELECT CURDATE() INTO @tFechaAct;

SELECT u.nombre INTO @tNombre FROM reserva r 
INNER JOIN credencial c ON r.idCredencial = c.id
INNER JOIN usuario u ON c.id = u.idCredencial 
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

SELECT CONCAT(tr.tipo, ' Nº ', tr.numeroDispositivo) AS reserva 
INTO @tReserva FROM tiporeserva tr 
INNER JOIN reserva r ON tr.id = r.idTipoReserva
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

SELECT CONCAT(h.horaComienzo, ' - ', h.horaFin) 
INTO @tHorario FROM horario h
INNER JOIN reserva r ON h.bloque = r.bloqueHorario
WHERE r.id = NEW.id;

INSERT INTO `reportes`(`tipoCambio`, `fechaCambio`, `rut`, `nombre`, `idCredencial`, `reserva`, `horario`) VALUES ('Reserva', @tFechaAct, @tRut, @tNombre, NEW.idCredencial, @tReserva, @tHorario);
END //
```

**Observación:** Analizando tu código profundamente noto dos cosas. La primera es que debes colocar una clave primaria a tu tabla reportes. La segunda es que no vas a poder crear tu trigger aún porque debes solventar el hecho de que le pides a MySQL que inserte un valor **NEW.idCredencial** pero no le indicas como obtenerlo. Probablemente esto te genere un error nuevo.

Te sugeriría revisar como incrementar un campo en un trigger o colocar idCredencial como autoincrementable luego de crear tu tabla reportes dado que en tu código muestras que `idCredencial` no tiene que seguir un patrón en especifico. De esta forma solucionarías lo de **NEW.idCredencial** porque no tendrías que tomar en cuenta el campo `idCredencial` en el insert del trigger ya que este sería autoincrementable. Un dolor de cabeza menos.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un Saludo!

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era con el orden de DECLARE, en cuanto a lo demás si tenía una PRIMARY KEY, pero al copiar el código olvidé colocarla. También existe la tabla reportes a la que hago alusión en el Trigger, por lo que todo funcionó bien. Gracias

Comment: @Alfredo "si tenía una PRIMARY KEY, pero al copiar el código olvidé colocarla" Con razón! Me parecía raro que no hubiese jaja. De nada, me alegra mucho que fue útil. Un saludo!